# NetCDF for Perl on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, 64-bit, netcdf

I'm helping one of our students do some data access with NetCDF files on Windows 7 (64-bit). We have the binding for our preferred language (Perl) but can't find a prebuilt NetCDF library binary, or figure out where to put it so the Perl executable can find it. Anyone have any starting breadcrumbs? We were hoping to avoid loading up a whole Cygwin GCC stack for this one purpose; really all we need is a DLL and the knowledge of the right place to put it.

TIA,

rw

Answer (score 1):

I remember when this used to be a real pain, but with modern Perl on Windows, modules that require C compilation can generally be installed as easily as on Linux.

[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) for Windows comes with a compiler environment already set up.

ActivePerl also lets you download a C compiler, but I haven't tried this myself.

It's a shame that NetCDF haven't released their module via CPAN, but you still should be able to use the compiler that comes with Perl.

I also found this alternative module:
http://search.cpan.org/~dhunt/PDL-NetCDF-4.05/netcdf.pd

Answer (score 0):

Here are the latest netCDF DLLs for Windows:

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs_rc/winbin.html

Comment: that link is broken - any suggestions for an alternative?